# Python Try and Except Confusion

Tags: python, try-catch

I have defined a class to contain a grid of points. I want to perform error checking on the keyword argument `Grid_Points` to make sure the user gives either a float or int for the number of points. I want there to be an error if they don't specify anything.

```
class MyGrid:
    def __init__(self, Grid_Points=None, L=0.0, R=1.0):
    Grid = np.linspace(start=L, stop=R,num=Grid_Points, retstep=True)
    self.Grid = Grid[0]
    self.dx = Grid[1]
```

I implemented the following `try` and `except` clauses. When I do `TestGrid = MyGrid()` I get an error that says `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Grid' referenced before assignment`.

What am I missing? I thought trying to do `linspace` within the `try` clause would result in an exception (because `Grid_Points` will be equal to `None`) and so it should go to the except clause and print out the statement I specified and then terminate execution of the code. I purposely chose to use `Exception` so it would catch anything (I'll use something more specific once I get this working at all). But the code appears to be getting past the `try` and `except` blocks.

```
class MyGrid:
    def __init__(self, Grid_Points=None, L=0.0, R=1.0):
    try:
        Grid = np.linspace(start=L, stop=R,num=Grid_Points, retstep=True)
    except Exception:
        print('Enter the number of grid points as either a float or int')
    self.Grid = Grid[0]
    self.dx = Grid[1]
```

Comment: Why did you expect it to terminate execution? `except` is what you do when you *don't* want an exception to terminate execution.

Comment: And why do you have a default value of `None` when `None` isn't a valid value?

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you expect your code to print and terminate -- but you forgot to terminate the code.  You handled the exception, so your execution proceeds directly to the rest of the code:

```
self.Grid = Grid[0]
self.dx = Grid[1]
```

Since `Grid` is undefined (the `linspace` call aborted), the code now faults and dies here.  You need a conditional clause of some sort to handle the case, such as moving the `self` assignments into your `try` block:

```
class MyGrid:
    def __init__(self, Grid_Points=None, L=0.0, R=1.0):
      try:
        Grid = np.linspace(start=L, stop=R,num=Grid_Points, retstep=True)
        self.Grid = Grid[0]
        self.dx = Grid[1]
      except Exception:
        print('Enter the number of grid points as either a float or int')
```

Better yet, don't terminate: simply [loop until you get a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: thank you for the helpful response. I thought if the code made it into the `except` block it would terminate. Since an exception is raised in the `try` block by the `linspace` (because of `None`, right?) shouldn't the code have gone to the `except` block where it terminates after `print` statement?

Comment: No -- refer to any tutorial on `try -- except`.  You went out of your way to tell the Python run-time system, "Don't worry about that exception: I can handle it!"  You overrode the default exception handler -- anything you want to happen at this point, you now have to explicitly code.